# Modify jquery hide/show box in order towork with multiple instances of the same divs

Tags: php, jquery

I have this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
        // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
        $('#slickbox').hide();
        // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('#slick-show').click(function() {
            $('#slickbox').show('slow');
            return false;
        });
        // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('#slick-hide').click(function() {
            $('#slickbox').hide('fast');
            return false;
        });
        // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
        $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
            $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**The problem is: how can I make the code work for multiple instances of the same divs?**

Like this it works for the divs from the first for loop.

**UPDATE: used classes, now all the divs are toggled at once. What I need is for example if I click on the third link generated by the loop, only the 3rd slickbox to be shown. Hope you understand.**

```
<?       for ($i = 1; $i <= get_option('category_nr'); $i++): 

         <table class="form-table">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="slick-toggle<? echo $i; ?>">Toggle the box</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="slickbox<? echo $i; ?>">
                Content
        </div>

<?      endfor; ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same `id` is not valid HTML and will have unpredictable results.  You need to use `class`es instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Every link toggles one div now.
The id of the link must be the same as the class of the div.

The code is untested:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle_link" id="toggle_1">link 1</a>
<div class="toggle_1">Box 1</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle_link" id="toggle_2">link 2</a>
<div class="toggle_2">Box 2</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a.toggle_link').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Silly me, yes, use classes.. but if I do this, all the divs will show. For example if I click on link 3 generated by the for loop I want only the number 3 table to show

Comment: @webmasters - To be more specific, you can add a new attribute like "clickid" to the element which will be clicked. Then to click/toggle event, you can get that value via jQuery's val() and trigger the dom using that id. I do it most the times.

Comment: i can add the id easily in php, but I don't know hot to do it using jquery... let me edit my question

Comment: Take a look at the edited php code to see what I mean, please. Now I have slick_toggle1, slick_toggle2, .... and slickbox1, slickbox2... I just need a way to make them work with jquery

Comment: You are not limited to use ID or class for bindings. You can add new attributes (like <a rel="blahblah") and bind it like $('a[rel="blahblah"]').toggle(....); etc as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: I just edited the answer above. I think that code should do what you want.

Comment: Ty very much, can the divs be hidden by default? How about applying a transition effect?

Comment: You can put a second class to the divs (ie: toggle_box).
Then you can set all divs with class toggle_box to "display: none;" in your CSS.

Please take a look here for the usage of the toggle() function:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Bind clicks into classes or other attributes instead of IDs.

E.g I'm making up a new attribure and binding to it.

```
$('div[rel="slickbox"]').hide();

<div rel="slickbox" id="slickbox">
```

I guess you got the idea.

P.s: IDs should be unique, don't use same IDs on loops, make them unique.

Edit: Updating the respond with a solution:

Sample HTML:

```
    <a class="click" id="id1" rel="1">Click me</a>
    <a class="click" id="id2" rel="2">Or me</a>
    <a class="click" id="id3" rel="3">Or to me</a>

    <br /><br />
    <div id="hidden1" class="hidden">First Hidden Div <button class="closeme">Close Me</button></div>
    <div id="hidden2" class="hidden">Second Hidden Div <button class="closeme">Close Me</button></div>
    <div id="hidden3" class="hidden">Third Hidden Div <button class="closeme">Close Me</button></div>​
```

Sample jQuery:

```
$(function(){

    $('.click').click(function(){
        if($('#hidden'+$(this).attr('rel')).is(':hidden')) {
            $('#hidden'+$(this).attr('rel')).show('fast');
        } else {
            $('#hidden'+$(this).attr('rel')).hide('fast');
        }
    });

    $('.closeme').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('div').hide('fast');
    });

});​
```

I had to update the toggle event and check its status each time its clicked, because the close button was killing toggle order (I mean, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5AAL/8/), open a div and close with close button inside div, and try to re-open from the main togglers. You'll see what I mean.)

Sample CSS:

```
.click {
 display:block;
 cursor:pointer;    
}

.hidden {
 display:none; /*hide for default*/
background:red;
 color: white;   
}
```

You can check from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y5AAL/5/). You can relate any link to anything you want this way.
​

Comment: Silly me, yes, use classes.. but if I do this, all the divs will show. For example if I click on link 3 generated by the for loop I want only the number 3 table to show

Comment: I responded to you at Robin's answer, check there. On my way to making  a sample code

Comment: Edited my respond, please give it a check. I also added a jsfiddle URL for you to check.

Comment: Ty very much, let me give it a test, much simpler then my sollution

Comment: It seems to work :) great, one more thing, do I need the styles?

Comment: Nah, I used them for grouping and for demo. But the display:none part of .hidden may be required, to get them hidden as default.

Comment: Tested it and it works great, you helped me allot. One more thing, how about a link at the bottom of the hidden div to close it. If it's a long div there is no sense in scrolling up towards the link to close it.

Comment: Updated my solution. Also updated the jsfiddle URL. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't generate multiple identical id's. Create an empty class "slickbox" and use

```
 <div id="slickbox_<?php print "$i"; ?>" class="slickbox">
```

and then jQuery select ".slickbox" instead of "#slickbox".

Edit: also check any other references to "slickbox" by id, if there are (e.g. in the CSS).

The click function then must refer not the id or class, but the clicked object:

```
$('.slick-show').click(function() {
        self.show('slow');
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Silly me, yes, use classes.. but if I do this, all the divs will show. For example if I click on link 3 generated by the for loop I want only the number 3 table to show

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what are you trying to achieve, but this seems to be it:

See this [Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/SX58R/2/)!

**Assuming the following HTML:**

```
<div id="actions">
    <button id="slick-show">Show all</button>
    <button id="slick-hide">Hide all</button>
</div>
<div class="slickbox">Hello</div>
<div class="slickbox">Hello</div>
<div class="slickbox">Hello</div>
<div class="slickbox">Hello</div>
<div class="slickbox">Hello</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  // define the target element
  var $target = $('.slickbox');

  // hides all by default
  $target.hide();

  // shows all
  $('#slick-show').bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $target.show('slow');
  });

  // hides all
  $('#slick-hide').bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $target.hide('fast');
  });

  // toggles the clicked one
  $target.bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggle(400);
  });

});
```

Comment: Its almost like this, not being english native (hard to explain). Instead of toggle all I need to toggle one by one. For example click on 4 and toggle it, click on 1 and toggle it